# Accessing Flash from template in Java

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

I'm very new to using the play framework and Scala.

My app is written using Play Framework 2.3 in Java and I'm setting a Flash in my controller.  However when I redirect to my view the Flash is always unavailable.

Just before I redirect, I've logged whether the Flash is set, and this logs true.

```java
public static Result upload() {
    flash("error", "test flash");
    System.out.println("flash " + flash().containsKey("error"));
    return redirect(routes.Application.upload());
}
```

in my template:

```html
<p>flash: @flash.get("error")</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaSessionFlash

Data in the Flash scope are kept for only one request.
I guess you have to read the data and put it in the flash once more:

```
String error = flash("error");
flash("error", error);
return redirect(routes.Application.upload());
```

Comment: But I set the flash right before the redirect, thats only one request??

Comment: your code reads the flash data and do not write it.
I think the goal of the flash scope is to write some data before a redirect.

Comment: I've not included the code for setting the flash, just the log that verifies it has been set

Comment: I think it wasn't working becuase the view wasn't reloaded, I switched flash to session and it's working fine.